# shorting URL with HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess

htaccess in this page

```
www.mysite.it/LABS/page.php?id=value
```

to

```
www.mysite.it/LABS/value
```

i try this but not work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} LABS/page\.php?name=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /page\.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Solutions?

Comment: thanks @Roozbeh J but not work :(

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /LABS/page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I usually use a mod_rewrite generator

[Source](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php)

Comment: Marco, does your server has mod_rewrite installed? It would be great if you copy all your .htaccess file here - Also can you let us know what exactly doesn't work? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /LABS/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: please vote for me : i explain you , its like you have to select base like your LABS and work for page.php? will remove

Comment: please vote for me answer +:  its like you have to select base like you have /LABS/ then it will remove page.php? then you will work this code